# Ubuntu Apache2 won't start

Tags: 12.04, apache2

```
 * Starting web server apache2
apache2: Syntax error on line 214 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Syntax error on line 3
of /etc/apache2/httpd.conf: Expected </> but saw </Directory>
Action 'start' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
   ...fail!
```

Comment: I think you should include the `httpd.conf` file in you question...

Comment: +1 for  franzlorenzon. What do you did before you restart apache. What files do you create modify?

Comment: Also the `/var/log/apache*.log`

Answer (score 5):

Reinstalling apache would be the most easy way to fix your problem. But you will also lose all your settings:

```
sudo apt-get purge apache2
sudo apt-get install apache2
```

If you want to fix the problem the elegant way, you will need to fix the error in you httpd.conf file by editing it and replacing `</>` by `</Directory>` on line 214 (like the error indicates quite clearly):

```
sudo nano /etc/apache2/httpd.conf
```

You could also use any other editor (e.g. gedit or vim)

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem with the file `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf`, on terminal type :

```
sudo gedit /etc/apache2/httpd.conf
```

on line 214 search a `</>` and change to `</Directory>` and save the file

or

try to reinstall apache
on terminal type :

```
sudo apt-get remove apache2
sudo apt-get install apache2
```

this occured because a problem with syntax, problably you change anything of the file

Comment: it would need to be a `sudo apt-get purge apache2` as its config files a regular remove would not remove the `httpd.conf` purge would blow away configs aswell.